# MySQL change last row of rollup

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, rollup

I am running a query for a report and am using rollup to get a total. One of my columns have a text field that is duplicating at the end. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions;

  transNum | itemid | description | qty
 ---------------------------------------
        01 |     01 |    DESC1    |  14
        02 |     01 |    DESC1    |  05
        03 |     01 |    DESC1    |  01
        04 |     02 |    DESC2    |  02
        05 |     02 |    DESC2    |  01
        06 |     02 |    DESC2    |  02
        07 |     03 |    DESC3    |  05
        08 |     03 |    DESC3    |  06
        09 |     03 |    DESC3    |  01

SELECT itemid,description,qty FROM transactions GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP;

    itemid | description | qty
   ----------------------------
        01 |    DESC1    |  20
        02 |    DESC2    |  05
        03 |    DESC3    |  12
           |    DESC3    |  37
```

This is a rough example, my actual data consists of multiple tables.

Now, I understand that the DESC3 is getting duplicated because I am not grouping by the description field, but is there any function that can get around this?

Other database engines have a GROUPING function, which is basically what I need but in MySQL.

Thank you for any help

Comment: What's the raw data in your table, and is there a reason you're explicitly *not* grouping by description? In fact does this even work without aggregates in non-grouped fields??

Comment: @lc.: MySQL can select even not aggregated columns

Comment: @juergend Hmm sounds like a bug rather than a "feature". I'm not sure I even understand where it would pull the data from... but ok...

Comment: I added a rough example of the raw data, the actual data has the descriptions in a separate item table.

Comment: Why don't you add `description` to `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @Xint0: if he adds `description`, the `rollup` will break the result when description changes... try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d611d/9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, then try this:

```
SELECT a.itemid, b.description, a.total
FROM
    (
        SELECT itemid, sum(qty) as total
        FROM transactions
        GROUP BY itemid WITH ROLLUP
    ) as a
    LEFT JOIN item b ON a.itemid=b.itemid
```

Assuming you have a table named `item` with item descriptions keyed on `itemid`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), there's no way of altering the content of the last row.

The result set comes with a `NULL` value in the `1st column` of the `rollup` row so that you can identify it in your application.

Here's a SQL Fiddle to play with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d611d/8

As you see it does repeat the previous description in the `rollup` row.

Comment: That is a nifty little tool I didn't know about. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use: `case when itemid  is null then Total`

Comment: You can format your code by using the {} button when editing your answer. It makes readability better.